# Use of 'for which' in this sentence

Tags: grammar

This is something a senior official wrote on a thank-you letter to someone. I'm just wondering whether the use of 'for which' is appropriate in this sentence.

> As presented during the seminar the development of public health terminologies and classification is of prime importance to us **for which** it is necessary that we all collaborate towards our collective mission to make a difference in the lives of people in the world.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to English Language & Usage. It seems to me that the wording you quote is so difficult to make sense of—before the reader even reaches the "for which" language—that assessing the appropriateness of "for which" may not be possible. In particular, "the development of public health terminologies and classification" is baffling to me. I note too that the sentence has no internal punctuation, though readers might benefit from a comma after _seminar_ and another comma after _us_.

Answer (score 1):

No, that "for which" is wrong." At a minimum, it should be "for which **reason**."

However, it's better to have it changed, e.g., to:

*As presented during the seminar, the development of public health terminologies and classification is of prime importance to us. **This is why** it is necessary that we all collaborate towards our collective mission **to make a** difference in the lives of people **of** the world.*

or:

*As presented during the seminar, the development of public health terminologies and classification is of prime importance to us. **This is why** it is necessary that we all collaborate towards our collective mission **of making a** difference in the lives of people **of** the world.*

I prefer "mission of making a", but "mission to make a" is more frequent at Google Books.

The comma is important too.

Comment: Thanks for your teaching. Now I'm going to teach the senior official what English grammar is.

Comment: Good luck. You'll have a better chance appealing to his "administrative assistant" (they used to call them secretaries) to intercept the senior official's so-called writing before letting it out into the world.